# Dynamic alias of aggregate functions on laravel's query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to have a dynamic alias of count() function.

I'm using mysql 5.7 as database.

Here's the code.

```
$date = Carbon::parse('2021-03-11')
DB::table('payments')
        ->select(DB::raw('IFNULL(sum(amount),0) as :date'), $date)
        ->get();
```

And with this im having this error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, `2021-03-11` from `payments`' at line 1 (SQL: select IFNULL(sum(amount),0) as :date, `2021-03-11` from `payments`)
```

Im expecting this result

```
|2021-03-11|
|<amount_here>|
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$date = Carbon::parse('2021-03-11')
DB::table('payments')
        ->select(DB::raw('IFNULL(sum(amount),0) as "?"', [$date])
        ->get();
```